# Power of a test, and repeated sampling

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, frequentist

I am currently studying frequentist theory and hypothesis testing and I came across this paragraph in my textbook which I'm finding rather difficult to interpret, particularly the line in bold -

"The fundamental notion is that of seeking a test which maximises power, **the probability under repeated sampling of correctly rejecting an incorrect hypothesis**, subject to some pre-specied fixed size, the probability of incorrectly rejecting a true hypothesis.

I'm not sure how to interpret what "repeated sampling" means in this context. Could anyone possibly shed any light on this? Thanks!

Comment: The statement is very confusing.  I want to ignore it for the moment and just try to explain the frequentist notion of repeated sampling.  Say that you have a statistical model and a parameter such as the population mean.  You construct a 95% confidence interval for the mean.  What is the frequentist interpretation.  It is not that the probability that the interval contains the parameter is 0.95 because you only generated this random interval once.  So you either included the parameter or you missed. The frequentist doesn't claim anything about this one sample.

Comment: This is where repeated sampling comes in. The frequentist says that the specific interval is constructed in such a way that if you repeated the sampling process say 1000 times that approximately 950 times the resulting interval will contain the parameter and approximately 50 times it will not.  You don't actual do the repeated sampling but you accept the fact that in the long run the procedure does what it is suppose to do.

Comment: This is a general idea of frequentist statistics and applies to hypothesis testing and any other form of statistical inference. This is quite different  from the Bayesian approach to statistical inference

Comment: The diagram and surrounding discussion [here](http://www.dcscience.net/2014/03/24/on-the-hazards-of-significance-testing-part-2-the-false-discovery-rate-or-how-not-to-make-a-fool-of-yourself-with-p-values/) may be helpful.

Comment: @user143964 Where did you get paragraph 2 from?